# gif images are not displayed which are stored in templates folder on running flask file

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm trying to add a gif image to my `index.html` page, where the gifs are stored in templates folder, but after running flask files the gif images are not displayed.

How can I solve this issue?

```
<header>
  <h2 id="spinner" ><img  class="animated-gif" src="gif2.gif">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;SUMMERISER</h2>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2):

The way you did it it will look for the gif at:

```
{Current-url}/gif2.gif
```

Therefore if you want to source it like that you have to define a route to the gif.

The correct way would be to put the gif in the 'static' folder and then generate a url to it like this:

```html
<img  class="animated-gif" src="{{url_for('static', filename='gif2.gif')}}" />
```